# Lravel return bad response on query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have this function

```
public function getConditionDescription($search){
   $condition = Condition::where("code", $search)->first();
   return $condition ? $condition->condition_description : "" ;
}
```

but when I pass "#" as parameter the query return the first row with code = 0.
in the nex image you can see an example.
[image]

Does anyone know how prevent or escape this case?

Comment: Im curious to know whats your environment setup? database, php, laravel version? are you also getting the same result if you pass the id `Condition::where('id', '#')->first();` can you remove the `->first()` and see what are the result

Comment: This is not an issue with Laravel, but rather how MySQL handles searches against integer columns when passed a string literal in the WHERE clause. What happens is MySQL will cast the string to an int and in this case when # is cast to an int the result is 0, e.g. `select CAST("#" AS UNSIGNED)`, this will return 0, so the query above becomes `SELECT * FROM conditions WHERE code = 0`.

Comment: thats actually right, if you pass a non-integer value into an int column for comparison, it actually cast that into an int, so any non-integer you pass will result your statement query a `0` value

Comment: Have you tried escape char like "\#"?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can do with this case,

1. make a route regex
2. use parameter type declaration

for the regex, you can check [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints) here,

and for the second method, you can change your code like so (if the code is integer):

```php
public function getConditionDescription( int $search ){

   $condition = Condition::where("code", $search)->first();
   return $condition ? $condition->condition_description : "" ;

}
```

Comment: the parameter not allways is an int